# Connect windows client with linux server

Tags: c#, linux, windows, server

I want to make some simple client-server apps, but I have only a linux server running and no windows server.
So what is needed so that I can connect my windows client app with my linux server app?

I mean, how is teamspeak for example doing it, running a linux/mac/windows server and you can connect with linux/max/windows client, so the system doesnt matter.

I hope you know what I mean, my english is not that best :D

Comment: What channel are you using? Sockets? REST? SOAP? and most importantly what have you tried?

Comment: Right now I'm not at home and I tried nothing. I just want to know in theory ^^ Found nothing usefull with google, may I searched wrong, don't know.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to make some simple client-server apps, but I have only a linux
>   server running and no windows server. So what is needed so that I can
>   connect my windows client app with my linux server app?

I think you can do it, through Virtual Machine. 
You can connect between your local server (Linux) and client server.

> I mean, how is teamspeak for example doing it, running a
>   linux/mac/windows server and you can connect with linux/max/windows
>   client, so the system doesnt matter.

For more information, look at : [Server](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/connect-two-servers-different-ip-addresses-49247.html), [how to set up client server in vm](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxKmakXetv4), [Network of Machines in VirtualBox with SSH Access](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S7jD6nnYJy0)